# SMT Chinese display questions

Tags: lcd

I am trying to underestand a chinese digital timer. So well, there are some things that are not shown on textbooks.

When I search about LCD screens i can't find anything related to this display:

[image]

I want some info about how it works and what it is, or where I can get it.
Thanks a lot. It had 15 pins attached to it instead of 14.

Comment: What model is this? (And I don't understand the relation to timers). Maybe it helps to know from what device it comes from.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Comes from this circuit:https://i.imgur.com/aqd7XNF.jpg. And this circuit is from this: https://www.amazon.es/GreenBlue-GB104-Temporizador-digital-planificador-semanal/dp/B00JAIQETE/ref=pd_sim_60_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=K07JHNMZB8DAP20Z0ZWV.

Comment: Crop the photo, man. Crop the photo.

Comment: Unclear what the OP is asking, and not responding to request to clean up image and provide more specific details. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a multiplexed LCD display (bare glass) with elastomeric connections (that rubber-like strip that you probably removed).

I can tell it's multiplexed because there are only 15 pins to control perhaps 30-35 segments. Probably triplexed- three backplanes. Such displays require somewhat complex AC waveforms to operate properly (improper operation can damage them over time).

They are available from various suppliers, however not commonly sold in small quantities. OEMs can get the display customized to their requirements with custom annunciators, size as desired, fluid for the desired temperature range and voltage etc.

You can find some with pins attached through distributors however they tend to be very expensive (relatively speaking) and often are static drive (so there are many pins- one per segment plus a backplane).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://slideplayer.com/slide/1718570/) is a simple explanation of how they work and how to specify them and connect to them using the Zebra rubber connections.

http://www.cloverdisplay.com/en/press.html

There are many competitors for this product. [image]

[not inches]